# Presymplectic formulation of mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations

Throught Rovelli's book ([Quantum Gravity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521715962)) he introduces very quickly the **presymplectic formalism** of mechanics in chapter 3 saying that's a "crucial step in the direction of the relativistic theory".

Does anyone know some reference (book/article) that explain this formulation in more details ?

Comment: 2003 draft version from author's website: http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~rovelli/book.pdf